# Oracle 12C silent installation with Ansible: unzip - invalid source path error

Tags: oracle, ansible, silent-installer

I am using an Ansible Role (https://github.com/cvezalis/oracledb-ansible) to install Oracle 12C R1 Enterprise on CentOS 7.

An Error occurs when the task /roles/oracle-install/tasks/main.yml tries to execute the following:

```
- name: Install Product  
command: '{{ installation_folder}}/database/runInstaller -silent -ignorePrereq -ignoreSysPrereqs -waitforcompletion -responseFile {{ installation_folder }}/db_install.rsp'
```

The log file:

```
Using paramFile: /Volume_Oracle_DB_Install/oracle/app/installation/database/install/oraparam.ini

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 12625 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4094 MB    Passed  

The commandline for unzip:

/Volume_Oracle_DB_Install/oracle/app/installation/database/install/unzip -qqqo ../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.6.0.75.0/1/DataFiles/\*.jar -d /tmp/OraInstall2017-07-26_08-28-16AM  

Invalid source path   Unzip command failed. Please check oraparam.ini and specify a valid source path.  
No umask is available from oraparam.ini. Using the default value '007'.`
```

Within "oraparams.ini" the source is defined as:
`SOURCE=../stage/products.xml`

Within the products.xml it says, one shouldn't edit the file by hand, but i wouldn't even know what to change.

I tried to get further information on the runInstaller and its params by reading [" Understanding Oracle Universal Installer Commands"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/em.112/e12255/c_oui_appendix.htm#OUICG378) but did not find a solution to my problem there.

How can I fix this error to get the runInstaller to install the product?
Could this eventually be a problem coming from the response file?